# Linux - Output to Folder that Yet Exists (in one command)

Tags: linux, command-line, redirection, pipe

Is it possible to achieve this in one command without requiring a script:

```
echo "test" > /folder/that/does/not/exist/newFile.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the closest I could come to a single-command solution:

```
install -Dm644 <(echo test) /folder/that/does/not/exist/newFile.txt
```

It only works with shells that support the `<( )`-style command substitution. This uses the same number of commands as the solution above:

```
mkdir -p /folder/that/does/not/exist; echo test > /folder/that/does/not/exist/newFile.txt
```

But at least the former solution looks somewhat like a single command.

Comment: Will these methods work if the command is put into a cron job?

Comment: The second one almost definitely will. The first one might, depending on your system.